# Is there a `quote`-like facility a la Lisp in Rascal

Tags: rascal

I know Rascal is intended to be a meta-language for other languages.  Do these languages include Rascal itself?  Is there any meta-facilities like `quote` a la Lisp available or planned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform Rascal using Rascal by including the Rascal syntax definition and simply using the normal quotes. We are not planning to add quoting at run-time for Rascal itself afaik.

One thing that I forgot to mention earlier, is that the "resources" mechanism can be used to manipulate Rascal code at "import" time. You can write any function as in:

```
@resource{myScheme}
str generateNewCode(str name, loc l) = ...
```

`generateNewCode` should generate a Rascal module with name `name`.

After this you can import as follows:

```
import MyModule = myScheme://someOtherModuleName;
```

And then the module that is generated by generateNewCode is imported by Rascal in the module that you typed the import in.

Nothing stops you from writing a generateNewCode function that parses another module, rewrites or extends it and then will be imported.

Comment: By normal quotes do you mean those for strings?

Comment: No, I meant the backticks for concrete syntax, as in `(Expr) \`1 + 2\``

Comment: So you can `import lang::rascal::\syntax::Rascal` and then use concrete matching or concrete construction expressions to manipulate Rascal programs.